# Android browser can't access the internet, adb shell can

Tags: android, networking, emulation, android-virtual-device

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 laptop but the Android emulator's networking is only half working, regardless of which AVD I run - a brand new one, one we have on our test servers, anything.

I can run `adb shell nc www.google.com 80` to get a malformed request response with plenty of HTML and CSS, and DNS canonicalising the server name. Hurrah.

But the browser and other apps running on the emulator don't display pages.

Strangely, Chrome's suggestions bar works, even for crazy things that it can't possibly have cached - but selecting one of the suggestions (or just typing an address directly) leaves its page-area white, the blue loading line going no further than about as wide as the https icon.

This happens with both an old and a recently downloaded SDK (emulator 26.1.4), and on a very recent (API 26/Oreo) and a very old (API 23/Mmallow) image, so it seems it's a machine issue. (Update: tried with a working machine's copy of emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64, no difference; tried with an ARM-based AVD, which... is still booting. Haha. 'Process system isn't responding'. Oh, here we go. Chrome... one mmmmmiiiiiinnnnnnuuuuuteeeeeee... crash. ARM==
 WebViewApp looks like it's doing the same 'fail to load' thing; ARM Maps sits there with a spinner... and eventually.. oh, a map... explore food and things near me... Cheap drinksh... text... with picturesh... Read more...? Nope, frozen.)

Since adb shell and AndroidChrome can make direct contact (even if only limited contact in the case of Chrome), it seems it's not a plain network issue.

Inside the AVD's network settings the only access point (T-Mobile) has no proxy, so it's not that.

The tail of the logcat, after asking the browser to follow its suggestion of FIFA something or other is:

```
09-12 11:44:49.357  2118  2118 I QSB.GoogleSearch: Got intent: #Intent;action=android.intent.action.WEB_SEARCH;category=android.intent.category.DEFAULT;launchFlags=0x800000;component=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.search.core.google.GoogleSearch;S.com.android.browser.application_id=com.android.browser;S.query=fifa%2018%20demo;end
09-12 11:44:49.384  2118  2118 W LocationOracleImpl: Best location was null
09-12 11:44:49.385  2118  2189 E ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.partnersetup.rlzappprovider
09-12 11:44:49.424  1623  2022 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://www.google.co.uk/... flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.android.browser cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity (has extras)} from uid 10019 on display 0
09-12 11:44:49.443  1623  2653 W ActivityManager: Duplicate finish request for ActivityRecord{8859f3a u0 com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.search.core.google.GoogleSearch t164 f}
09-12 11:44:49.472  1623  2111 W InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@eb4d1d attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@feb6c7d
09-12 11:44:49.488  3051  3051 D WebViewTimersControl: onBrowserActivityResume
09-12 11:44:49.488  3051  3051 D WebViewTimersControl: Resuming webview timers, view=com.android.browser.BrowserWebView{d9270d2 VFEDHVCL. .F...... 0,0-540,859}
09-12 11:44:52.013  1347  1683 W audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 2277855 , only wrote 2140979
09-12 11:44:54.470  1623  2111 I AccountManagerService: getTypesVisibleToCaller: isPermitted? true
09-12 11:45:00.074  1259  1314 D hwcomposer: hw_composer sent 440 syncs in 60s
09-12 11:46:00.061  1259  1314 D hwcomposer: hw_composer sent 6 syncs in 60s
```

I'm a bit stumped by this. Firefox on the machine's desktop is happy. Any ideas?

---

I've raised https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65613698

---

Maps seems happy to display maps and other information and pictures, so maybe it's actually something like a host graphics card issue, that's triggering in a way that makes it look like webviews aren't loading, without actually crashing them?